# CSS Star Rating with ng-repeat and json data using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Want to show a `div` n times according to the value which was received from JSON.

**My object:**

```
$scope.pro = [
    {
        product: "chicken", 
        rating: 3
    },
    {
        product: "fish", 
        rating: 3
    },
    {
        product: "pizza", 
        rating: 4
    }
];
```

If a product has 3 ratings means the `div` have to show three times, like a star rating.
How to do it in angular.js?

[My Plunker Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/Gosf7WcKYS8WV8qC7i5u/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this,

JS

```
$scope.pro = [{product: "chicken", rating: 3},{product: "fish", rating: 3},{product: "pizza", rating: 4}];

var ratingTotal = 5; 

$scope.getRepeater = function() {
   return new Array(ratingTotal);
};
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">

    <div ng-repeat="array in pro">{{array.product}} <span class="star-icon" ng-repeat="r in getRepeater() track by $index" ng-class="{'full': ($index + 1) <= array.rating, 'half': ($index + .5) == array.rating}" ></span></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**Note**: The class name for selected star is mentioned as 'full' and feel free to change this.

Comment: can i know how to print the remaining divs (i.e) i want to loop 5 values ., 3 value from json + 2 other value ? as like a star ratings

Comment: Is it always 5?

Comment: Can changed...  We can go for five

Comment: So the total star count is 5 which can be changed later and based on the 'array.rating' you have to highlight the selected star using a CSS class, am I right?

Comment: Give me the CSS class name for the selected star as mentioned above and I will make the code change.

Comment: You can take this https://coderwall.com/p/iml9ka/star-ratings-in-css-utf8

Comment: Okay, I have updated the code above with a class 'full' as per the link.

Comment: super and simple ..i created a plunker  [DEMO](https://embed.plnkr.co/dDqwkIARDEnn6My3mlZP/) .. can we define half star's?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array, based on the rating. Then repeat over that array:

```
<div ng-repeat="array in pro">
    {{array.product}} , <span ng-repeat="n in createArray(array.rating) track by $index">X</span>
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.createArray = function(n){    
    return new Array(n);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/gUPn6m7Tiu01yksa9VOs?p=preview

Comment: The plunker is the same as the OP's

Comment: @devqon can i know how to print the remaining divs  (i.e) i want to loop 5 values ., 3 value from json + 2 other value ? as like a star ratings .

Answer (score 3):

`geNumber()` will create an empty array with the size of the rating. `ng-repeat` will iterate over it no matter what is inside

`track by $index` is necessary in this case because you will display multiple times the same value and duplicates in a repeater are not allowed

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.pro = [{
    product: "chicken",
    rating: 3
  }, {
    product: "fish",
    rating: 3
  }, {
    product: "pizza",
    rating: 4
  }];
  
  $scope.getNumber = function(num){
    return new Array(num);
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

  <div ng-repeat="item in pro">
    <div ng-repeat="n in getNumber(item.rating) track by $index">
      {{item.product}}
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling fancy, you can use this **ES6** solution to show *x number of **:
Note: no IE support at all.

**JS**

```
$scope.getAsterisks = rating => Array.from('*'.repeat(parseInt(rating, 10)));
```

**HTML**

```
<span ng-repeat="x in getAsterisks(array.rating) track by $index">{{x}}</span>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9H3j3NH9w5xNvqM142Gq?p=preview

**Info on the ES6 functions:**
`Array.from` (no support in IE) creates an array from a string, each character becomes an array item.
`String.prototype.repeat` (no support in IE and Opera) ... repeats the string X times.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="array in pro">{{array.product}} ,
  <span ng-repeat=" arr in array.rating ">{{arr.j}}</span>
</div>
```

// Code goes here

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.pro = [{product: "chicken", rating: 3},{product: "fish", rating: 4},{product: "pizza", rating: 6}];
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.pro.length;i++)
  {
     if($scope.pro[i].rating >0)
     {
         $scope[$scope.pro[i].product]=[];
         for(var j=0;j< $scope.pro[i].rating;j++)
         {
            $scope[$scope.pro[i].product].push({j:'*'}); 
         }
         $scope.pro[i].rating = $scope[$scope.pro[i].product];
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">

    <div ng-repeat="array in pro">{{array.product}} ,
      <span ng-repeat=" arr in array.rating ">{{arr.j}}</span>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to create a star component via a custom directive it can also be reused throughout the Angular app, this directive takes the rating and generates the number of stars in the DOM.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .controller('StarController', StarController)
  .directive('star', star);

function DefaultController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.products = [{
    product: "chicken",
    rating: 3
  }, {
    product: "fish",
    rating: 4
  }, {
    product: "pizza",
    rating: 5
  }];
}

function star() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      rating: '=',
      max: '='
    },
    link: linkFunc,
    controller: StarController,
    controllerAs: 'star',
    bindToController: true
  };

  return directive;

  function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
      var fillStyle = '';
      if (i < scope.rating) {
        fillStyle = 'fill';
      } else {
        fillStyle = 'empty';
      }

      element.append('<span class="star-icon ' + fillStyle + '">☆</span>');
    }
  }
}

function StarController() {
  var vm = this;
}
```

```css
ul {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  padding: 10px;
}
ul li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
star span {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
.star-icon {
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
.star-icon.fill:before {
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #FDE16D;
  content: '\2605';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.star-icon.empty:before {
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #FFF;
  content: '\2605';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="product in ctrl.products">
        <span ng-bind="product.product"></span>
        <star rating="product.rating" max="5"></star>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Star rating inspired by https://coderwall.com/p/iml9ka/star-ratings-in-css-utf8

Comment: is there any way to show non full fill star ? ..  out of five ?

Comment: @RamanaaGj, I didn't get you, could you please elaborate what non full fill star out of five means, are you asking how to show 4.5 out of 5 stars something like that ?

Comment: My scenario was above is ok for me but in my case wanted to show like this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRgnpnK8Gm81TmPR3SeoQztFGDPl23jkYdE5xkOgLBT_Q60F9IDgA

Comment: Out of 5 there should be three golden  and then remaining will be of gray star .. Like tht..

Answer (score 1):

An AngularJS directive `ratings`:

```js
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .directive('ratings', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: false,
            template: '<span ng-repeat="x in arrRating track by $index">&#9733;</span>',
            link: function ($scope, $el, $attr) {
                $scope.arrRating = new Array(+$attr.rating);
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.pro = [{product: "chicken",rating: 3}, {product: "fish",rating: 3}, {product: "pizza",rating: 4}, {product: "steak",rating: 10}];
    });
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="p in pro">
     {{p.product}} <ratings rating="{{p.rating}}"></ratings>
  </div>
</div>
```